# Creating a counter from a dictionary

Tags: dictionary, get, counter

I'm new to learning python! I can't figure this out. The goal of this programme is to see how many keys there are in a given dictionary and count the amount of unique keys. The value of the key is irrelevant.

Input:

```
list = {"A": "apples", "B":"apples", "A":"bananas", "D":"oranges","A":"grapes", "B": "bananas", "C": "apples"}
count = {}

for i in list.keys(): 
    count.get(i,0)
    count[i] = count.get(i,0) + 1 

print(count)
```

What I want is this:

```
 {'A': 3, 'B': 2, 'C': 1, 'D': 1}
```

However I get this:

```
{'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'D': 1, 'C': 1}
```

Why does this happen and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this because when you make the `dictionary` a `list`, it removes all the duplicate elements.
I'll try and find a solution.

*EDIT: Are your values randomized?*

Comment: Yes thank you for looking into it. I suspected that it would remove duplicate values. All values are randomised.

Comment: Oh, easy! Gimme a minute to get the code, but basically, all you have to do is reverse the dictionary!

Comment: The Keys and values are made up and are random, however would it be possible to get the output without changing the order of the dictionary?